# why doesn't Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection Class have its own Contains method?

Tags: c#, linq

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection Class` implements the `contains` through extension method from `IEnumerable`, which is O(n)

why doesn't it have a native one with O(1)? it's kind of HashSet isn't it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235840/dictionary-keys-contains-vs-containskey-are-they-functionally-equivalent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does implement its own [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673071.aspx). You can't implement an interface through an extension method. Note that it implements it explicitly, which means you first have to cast it to `ICollection` to use it.

Comment: Also, `Enumerable.Contains` checks if its parameter implements `ICollection<T>`, so the operation is O(1) even if you call it via the extension method. That is, `dict.Keys.Contains` is just as fast as `dict.ContainsKey` (ignoring the creation of the `KeyCollection` object itself, which is trivial anyway).

Comment: my bad, didn't see the explicit methods part in MSDN