# Dictionary Keys.Contains vs. ContainsKey: are they functionally equivalent?

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, equivalence

I am curious to know if these two are functionally equivalent in all cases.

Is it possible that by changing the dictionary's default comparator that these two would be functionally different?

Also, isn't `Keys.Contains` almost guaranteed to be slower?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These two functions do exactly the same thing.

`Keys.Contains` exists because `Keys` is an `ICollection<TKey>`, which defines a `Contains` method.
The standard `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` implementation (the class, not the interface) defines it as

```
bool ICollection<TKey>.Contains(TKey item){ 
    return dictionary.ContainsKey(item); 
}
```

Since it's implemented explicitly, you can't even call it directly.

---

You're either seeing the interface, which is what I explained above, or the LINQ `Contains()` extension method, which will also call the native implementation since it implements `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: No, it won't be slower; I checked the source.  Also, if the compile-time type of your dictionary reference is the interface, it will call `ICollection<TKey>.Contains`, not the LINQ method.

Comment: I see now that I am indeed calling the extension method.

Comment: The only way that the LINQ method would be avoided was if you were using `IDictionary<T,U>`, not `Dictionary<T,U>` for your variable, though... right?

Comment: @ReedCopsey: That's exactly what I said.  (Or if you explicitly cast `Keys` to `ICollection<TKey>`)

Comment: Thanks - (it wasn't clear to me that you were referring to `IDictionary<T,U>`, from what you typed...)  You already had my upvote, though ;)

Comment: If you are using System.Linq then myDictionary.Keys.Contains( key ) will statically bind to Enumerable.Contains which is an O(n) operation. DO NOT DO THIS!!  You should always use  myDictionary.ContainsKey( key ) or even better, myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value)

Comment: @mhand: Wrong on both counts.  `Enumerable.Contains` is O(1) on `KeyCollection`, and overload resolution will prefer instance methods to extension methods.  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1241

Comment: @SLaks Hmm good point, I must have overlooked the cast in the Enumerable.Contains implementation, which will end up calling ICollection<TKey>.Contains and delegate properly like you stated. However, the compiler will bind to Enumerable.Contains unless it is statically known as ICollection<TKey>, but it seems to be a moot point given the cast to ICollection<TKey> in the Enumerable.Contains implementation

Comment: @mhand: Yes, and `IDictionary<K, V>.Keys` is an `ICollection<K>`.

Comment: Also worth noticing that `Contains()` can accept an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for a custom equality comparer.

Answer (score 12):

Although they are pretty much equivalent for `Dictionary<,>`, I find it's much safer to stick with `ContainsKey()`.

The reason is that in the future you may decide to use `ConcurrentDictionary<,>` (to make your code thread-safe), and in that implementation, `ContainsKey` is significantly faster (since accessing the `Keys` property does a whole bunch of locking and creates a new collection).