# Pass Dictionary KeyCollection mainaining the access speed

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, .net-2.0

I have a class that only uses the keyCollection of a `Dictionary<long, object>`, and I would like to pass to other class only the keys.

I know that the dictionary has a theorical `O(1)` access-by-index (as a `HashTable`) but if I convert the keyCollection to a List, the access would change to `O(n)`.

How could I pass the keyCollection to my class maintaining the `O(1)` access?

Edit: I'm using .NET 2.0.

Comment: Define "access"... if you mean "read by index", the access remains O(1), and indeed is a must *faster* O(1) than a hash-table. Indeed, the O(1) only applies to access-the-value-by-key, which makes no sense in a list **of the keys** - what is it you want to do with the list?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes, I mean acces by index (.Contains())

Comment: @MarcGravell: I need the key collection only to know if the dictionary CONTAINS certain key values, so I only need the keys.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235840/dictionary-keys-contains-vs-containskey-are-they-functionally-equivalent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a comment, you mention that your intent here is `.Contains()`. In that case, what you are looking for is `HashSet<T>`, which does exactly that - it just holds keys (no values), and provides fast `Contains` checks. So; for your `Dictionary<long,object>` you could do something like:

```
var set = new HashSet<long>(dictionary.Keys);
```

and pass that over. For convenience, `HashSet<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` (if you want to scope it to an interface, rather than the concrete type) - this has a `Contains` too.

Actually, it may be more efficient to use (which also works on .NET 2.0):

```
ICollection<long> = dictionary.Keys;
```

and pass that; the implementation of `Contains(key)` on this is O(1), since it is implemented via:

```
bool ICollection<TKey>.Contains(TKey item)
{
    return this.dictionary.ContainsKey(item);
}
```

Comment: And, assuming you have control over the class, it should really accept `ISet<T>` rather than `HashSet<T>`. (To avoid having to copy the keys from the dictionary to a set you could create a wrapper class which takes a dictionary and implement the `ISet<T>` methods.)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly I was asking. Thanks.

Comment: @Porges `ISet<T>` doesn't provide many useful methods for this case, actually - it is the `ICollection<T>` (which `ISet<T>` demands) which is useful.

Comment: This is true... just substitute `ICollection<T>` into what I said, then. ;)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Arrg, It's new on .NET 4.0. I'm using .NET 2.0. What about the Contains() performance of the KeyCollection?

Comment: @DanielPeñalba it is in 3.5, actually; and KeyCollection has no Contains() method. Edit: oops, the `KeysCollection` implements `ICollection<TKey>` - should work fine

Comment: @Daniel: Please remember next time to add details like framework version to your question, so that people don't invest too much time into an answer that won't work for you.

Comment: Actually, the `KeyCollection` returned by `Keys` has `O(1)` lookup. It just calls the underlying dictionary's `ContainsKey`. So, you don't need to do any extra work apart from accepting an `ICollection<TKey>`.

Comment: @MarcGravell: KeyCollection does have Contains, it's just that it's an explicit interface implementation.

Comment: @Porges: Wow, I thought that KeyCollection was O(n), perfect, so, please, could you post your answer, converting to ICollection<T>. I will mark as answered.

Comment: @DanielPeñalba actually, it looks like just using the `ICollection<TKey>` aspect of `KeyCollection<,>` will work fine; I've checked it in reflector - it is `bool ICollection<TKey>.Contains(TKey item)
{
    return this.dictionary.ContainsKey(item);
}

 

 
`

Comment: @DanielPeñalba also; an *interface* **does not have** a defined O(?) - it is only specific implementations where that makes sense. In this case, `KeyCollection<,>` implements `ICollection<TKey>.Contains` in an O(1) way.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Good point, I meant KeyCollection is O(1) not ICollection (sorry).

Comment: Someone wants to post the answer?